# Gtk theme in GTK# (Windows)

Tags: mono, gtk, gnome, cairo, gtk#

I'm trying to change the theme in GTK# (**OS: Windows, IDE: Xamarin**). But I get next issues:

1. I was able to find only one theme which correctly render, it is "Orta". All was well, except for **lags and freezes**. Here is my code:

   `string Resource_File = "Orta\\gtk-2.0\\gtkrc";
    Application.Init ();
    Gtk.Rc.AddDefaultFile (Resource_File);
    Gtk.Rc.Parse (Resource_File);
    MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
    win.Show ();
    Application.Run ();`

   **When I changing the size of the Paned or clicking on button I get GUI freezes**([I already asked about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434953/how-to-redraw-gtk-gui-asynchronously)). This problem occurs only when using this theme, with the other themes all works tolerably. I used the search and found a couple of opinions, about that this is due to the use of Cairo to render graphics ([one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507918/gtk-gtksharp-poor-performance-in-windows)).
2. if I try to use a different theme, **a lot of GUI elements not correctly rendered** in my GTK# application, but they are correctly render in the GTK Theme Selector. If the theme is displayed correctly in GTK Theme Selector, then I try to use the selected gtkrc file in my Gtk# app(as shown in Example with "Orta"), but almost always, most  widgets are not displayed correctly([here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349493/how-to-change-gtk-theme-in-gtk-on-windows))

So I have a few questions:

1. How to choose a work theme?
2. How to set a theme for GTK# (Windows)?
3. What Gtk# open source application using the theme and how?
4. What other way to change the style of GUI in the GTK# app?
5. Why "Orta" theme freezes?

So I need any your help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but I've been fighting with themes lately.

It turns out that when running a Gtk# app build with Xamarin, theme issues will appear because it seems that some "Windows-like" theme is forced into the code.

When running the application from Xamarin Studio, depending on the .Net framework (Microsoft .NET 4.5, Mono 3.3.0, Mono 4.0.1) the behaviour was different. And I had a warning with Mono 3.3.0, telling me the 'Xamarin' engine could not be found.

I ended up with the following code :

```
Application.Init ();
Gtk.Settings.Default.ThemeName = "Theme/gtk-2.0/gtkrc";
Gtk.Rc.Parse ("./Theme/gtk-2.0/gtkrc");
```

Where gtkrc is my theme. Without setting the default theme name, nothing worked correctly. I didn't go very far into customizing my theme, so I can't tell if it solves every theme issue.